# Formatting and partitioning a 3TB disk?

Tags: windows-8, external-hard-drive, formatting

Have a 3TB Lacie minumus disk.  External with USB3.0.  I can see the thing okay, but can't seem to format it as NTFS or exFAT on windows 8.1.

No matter what I do, it just shows as RAW.  Using the simple volume wizard I can create a new volume, format it etc., but at the end it does not show as NTFS or exFAT.  If I right click on the volume itself and select `Format` I get an error for Virtual Disk Manager that says `No such interface supported`.

This is a dell 9020 mid tower machine if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like the something is defective.  You will need to isolate the *actual* problem, and work through diagnosis incrementally:

- Do other USB devices work?  Do you have any other external storage devices?
- Have you tried a different USB port? (Preferably on a different USB root device.)
- Do you have the latest firmware, bios and drivers installed both for your computer and for  your drive?
- Scan for malware, with your anti-virus and *malware bytes*.
- Can you format the drive on another computer?
- What version of USB is the drive, and what version(s) do you have for the ports?
- Try a different Cable?

Good luck.

Comment: So interestingly, the drive works fine and is formattable on a different computer (a samsung laptop no less).  So it seems to be something with the Dell 9020 and/or USB interface.  Or even more likely something with the GPT interface.

Comment: Could also be an incompatablity between the USB chipset on your computer, and the USB chipset on your drive.  Make sure you have the latest drivers / updates for everything on your Dell, including the drive.  Or if you bought drive from a place that has a satisfaction guarantee you can get a refund.

Answer (score 0):

I've had problems with a scanner that was attached via USB. At first I thought that the (quite expensive) scanner was broken. Then I thought that the USB port on the computer was the problem. This very old computer had a built in USB port on the front, and built in USB ports in the back, plus a (PCI?) USB card on the back. I tried all three, the problem stayed.

Then I had that lightbulb moment: the cable! Stupid me, but I only saw the simplest solution the last, and that solved my problem. It was an expensive cable btw, one of the few that I've thrown away because of problems.

Comment: Thanks, but the drive did work on another machine...

Comment: Exactly - so did the scanner. All I'm saying is that you have to check all elements in the chain. In my case it was the cable, which is actually the easiest to check and cheapest to replace.